# JAVA: basic programming help needed, what code executes by default

Tags: java

I am trying to practice for my programming exam. Only problem is in all of these examples we have done in class there has been a GUI written and we just have to input in the method bodies.

I am writing a program here, and I just need the information from operations() method to print in the output window.

```
 package frenchbinarytreepractice;

 /**
 *
 * @author Sam
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
}

//Building Binary Trees
class bTree {

static class Node { //remember to initilize a root

    String value;
    Node left, right;

    Node(String value, Node left, Node right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    Node(String value) //THIS IS A SIBLING CONSTRUCTOR
    {
        this(value, null, null);
    }
}

private Node root;

static void creator() {
    Node root = new Node("ROOT");
    Node lefty = new Node("LEFT0");
    Node righty = new Node("RIGHT0");
    root.left = lefty;
    root.right = righty;
}

//This method will find the size of a node
public int size(Node r)
{
    if(r==null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1+(size(r.left)+size(r.right));
    }
}
public static void operations()
{
    System.out.println("Size of main: " + size(root));
}
}
```

Comment: System.out.println will print to stdout not to your gui. Since I don't know what's the gui implementation - just use eclipse's logcat to see the log message.

Comment: Ok, duffymo, no this is clearly not what I am asking. All I am asking is what code will be executed by default. Can you read!?

Comment: Why a down vote on the question? It's a language specific question which I myself was searching once started learning JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

The code which is executed once you run Java app is inside

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the actual answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

As per the standard, the `main` method is executed. Have a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As per you problem it looks like ,your class Main should be modified as

```
 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  bTree.creator();
  bTree.operations();
 }
}
```